# Other direction of theorem of mean value of Lagrange

Tags: calculus

I have test in calculus and I need help with old tests I'm trying to do.

We have open interval $\;J\;$ and $\;f:J\to\Bbb R\;$ which is differentiable two times in point $\;a\in J\;$ .

Assume $\;f''(a)>0\;$ . As hint, they say we can use the next function

$$g(h)=f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h$$

to show that there are $\;x_1\,,\,x_2\in J\;,\;\;x_1<a<x_2\;$ , s.t.

$$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=f'(a)$$

This is what I think is like opposite of Lagrange Theorem of mean value.

They also ask if above is true if $\;f''(a)<0\;$ or if $\;f''(a)=0\;$ .

Now, this is what I did: I assume  that $\;h\;$ is so small that $\;(a-h,a+h)\subset J\;$, so the hint above is fine, and then

$$\frac{g(h)}h=\left(\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h-f'(a)\right)\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}0$$

and I think that perhaps we could take $\;x_2=a+h\;,\;\;h>0\;,\;\;x_1=a+h\;,\;\;h<0\;$ , but it's confusing the condition $\;f''(x)\;$ and I'm stuck here, though I think that since $\;g\;$ is defined at least in $\;(a-h,a+h)\;$, the above shows that $\;g'(0)\;$ exists and equals zero, but I don't understand how this helps.

They also didn't give $\;f\;$ differentiable, or even only continuous in all of $\;J\;$ , only two times differentiable  in one single point $\;a\;$ .

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got  tip from a professor and I could reach answer.

First, since $\;f''(a)\;$ exists we deduce $\;f'(x)\;$ exists in some neighborhood of this point, and we suppose all happens in here.

Since $\;f''(a)>0\;$ we can assume $\;f'(x)\;$ is monotone ascendent in other subinterval of the above one, because for small $\;h\;$ it must be

$$\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}h>0\implies \begin{cases}f'(x)>f'(a)&,\;\;x>a\\{}\\f'(x)<f'(a)&,\;\;x<a\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{in the neighborhood}$$

We  therefore have that in our neighborhood $\;g(x)\ge 0\;$ and $\;g'(0)=0\;$ , because

$$\begin{align}&g'(h)=f'(a+h)-f'(a)\begin{cases}<0&,\;\;h<0\\>0&,\;\;h>0\end{cases}\\{}\\&\text{and also}\;\;g'(0)=f'(a)-f'(a)=0\end{align}$$

which means $\;(0,0)\;$ is a minimum point of $\;g\;$. Since it is continuous in our neighborhood, we can find $\;h_1<0<h_2\;$ with $\;g(h_1)=g(h_2)\;$ , but this means

$$f(a+h_1)-f'(a)h_1=f(a+h_2)-f'(a)h_2\iff\frac{f(a+h_2)-f(a+h_1)}{h_2-h_1}=f'(a)$$

and now we just put $\;x_2=a+h_2\;,\;\;x_1=a+h_1\;$ .

The result follows also for $\;f''(a)<0\;$, but fails for $\;f''(a)=0\;$ , for example with $\;f(x)=x^3\;$, since this function is injective.

Thank you very much for anyone who read and tried this problem, which is part of an exam from 2010. I think somebody told me they had to change this question or else add some points to the general grades as nobody at all chose it. I understand why  was that.